# Ruby on Rails login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, user-roles

for a university project i have to create a small ruby on rails application, in Netbeans, which allows staff of the university to maintain their absence records.

The sample logins available in books have been regarding a singular user table. My application will require 3 types of users staff (who are assigned to a manager), manager and admin (to create/edit/delete all employees). Thus the login will have to bring up a particular users home page, in steps my confusion.

My table structure at the moment has the field user_id in both the manager and staff table which has a 'has_one' relationship with ID of the users table which simply contains the fields user_id, user_name password and user_type.

I can't get any adapted sample code for logins to work with this multi user application, any insights or ideas on tutorials available similar to this?

Cheers.

P.S. I have the full spec available if any other further information is required.

Comment: what have you tried exactly? It seems that using some common logic to authenticate based on your users table should be ok. After that, at the end of the authentication logic (e.g. if you have a `SessionsController` in the `new action`) you can just redirect based in what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell from your question if you already have authentication working.

But, I've set up similar systems using the devise and cancan gems.

With devise, you just need to specify the root path in config/routes.rb and your user will be redirected there upon signin. For example you could have a route like this:

```
namespace :user do
   match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index', :as => :root
end
```

Then, in dashboard#index, you could provide profile-specific actions. Also, a good way to manage user roles would be to put a role column on the users table and use the cancan gem.
Check out this railscast on the subject http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan... So you could assign someone to the admin role, and using cancan's simple DSL they could create/edit/delete all employees.